# Select rows with minimum date

Tags: php, mysql

[image: sample data]

How to select row for each Code with minimum date?

The result should be ..

1. HS00001 2014-01-10
2. HS00002 2014-03-10
3. HS00003 2014-08-20

P.S.  This is neither H.W. nor Assignment.     I am just trying to create a template in wordpress using php and mysql database.

Comment: Where's `Marc B` when you need him; you know, `RT_M` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the revised question... I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM House as H
WHERE date = (
    SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM House
    WHERE H.code = code
  )
GROUP BY code
```

The `GROUP BY code` makes sure that even if there are multiple entries with the same `MIN(date)` then only one will be selected. Which one is selected, however, is random unless you add more stuff into that subquery to filter it more.

Comment: I have tried the LIMIT into my query but it only give me a single line   If ok, can you revise my question again Please?  I've add some more information into my post.

Comment: Much better, thanks for that question update :) That should do what you want

Comment: If this worked for you then mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a lot like HW, so I won't give you the code, but it looks like all the houses are from Toronto, so you'll want to have a `WHERE` clause with `Toronto` somewhere in there, and then you will also want to have an `ORDER BY date DESC` clause

In your PHP, you'll probably want a [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) in there, and loop through that and display what you want in a table format

Comment: Not a Homework...  Can you please review my question again?  I've added some more information