# JPQL Query to select row with minimum value

Tags: java, sql, jpql

Similar to [SQL query to select distinct row with minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291506/sql-query-to-select-distinct-row-with-minimum-value) and [Select rows with minimum date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961308/select-rows-with-minimum-date) but I am asking specifically for JPQL because the examples provided return `*` but I would want it to be the same object.

Say I have the query like this.

```
from BillingTargetDiscountAmount g 
  where g.billingTarget = :billingTarget 
   and g.discountSource = :discountSource 
   and g.startDate <= :date
```

I also have a composite key of

```
@Data
public class BillingTargetDiscountAmountPK implements Serializable {
    @ToString.Exclude
    private BillingTarget billingTarget;

    private String discountSource;

    private LocalDate startDate;

    @ToString.Include
    private Integer billingTargetID() {

        return billingTarget.getId();

    }

}
```

My guess would be something like though I am not sure what to do with the specific synax

```
select * [??? BillingTargetDiscountAmount ] from (
  select g.billingTarget, g.discountSource, min(g.startDate), other fields
  from BillingTargetDiscountAmount g 
    where g.billingTarget = :billingTarget 
     and g.discountSource = :discountSource 
     and g.startDate <= :date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I only needed to do one column for the min value.  I did a subselect and just repeated the parameters

```
from BillingTargetDiscountAmount btda 
where btda.billingTarget = :billingTarget and 
      btda.discountSource = :discountSource and 
      btda.startDate = (
        select min(g.startDate)
          from BillingTargetDiscountAmount g 
          where g.billingTarget = :billingTarget 
            and g.discountSource = :discountSource 
            and g.startDate <= :date
      )
```